# displaying data from .txt file

Tags: java

need help, i want to display the name of the person who just logged in, here is my login code

```
public void Masuk(){
    try {
        String lokasi = "D:/settings.txt";
        String username = txtUser.getText();
        String password = txtPass.getText();


        FileReader fr = new FileReader(lokasi);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line, user, pass;
        boolean isLoginSuccess = false;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            user = line.split(" ")[1].toLowerCase();
            pass = line.split(" ")[2].toLowerCase();
            if (user.equals(username) && pass.equals(password)) {
                isLoginSuccess = true;
                this.dispose();
                new Main_Menu(this, rootPaneCheckingEnabled).show();

                break;
            }
        }


        if (!isLoginSuccess) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "USERNAME/PASSWORD WRONG", "WARNING!!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
        fr.close();


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the login is in form, i used JDialog to dipslay the name of the person who just logged in(MainMenu), here is my MainMenu code right now

```
public void Berhasil(){
    String data = "D:/Settings.txt";

    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(data);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = br.readLine(),nama;

        nama = line.split(" ")[0].toLowerCase();
        String message = "Selamat datang "+ nama;



        String text;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)

            txtBerhasil.setText(""+message);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        fnfe.getMessage();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.getMessage();
    }
}
```

the .txt file looks like this

Name Username Password

i only want to write the name of the person who just logged in

Comment: What the specific problem? What have you tried?

Comment: What is the issue you're facing?

Comment: can you please be more specific?
understood the expectation - you want only name to be printed,
but what are you actually getting??

Comment: i want to display the first line of the .txt file, based on the account they used for login, sorry for my bad english

Comment: You don't need to read the file again. You have already established the User Name during the successful Login. Upon successful login place the User Name into a global field. Access that field whenever needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to read some text (the user's information) from a text file. There are several ways to do it. This is one way:

```
File file = new File("path/to/file.txt");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
String thisLine = null;
while (sc.hasNextLine()){
   thisLine = sc.nextLine();
}
```

Now you can do whatever you want with `thisLine`. Say you want the first word in the first line:

```
String[] words = thisLine.split(" ");
System.out.println(words[0]);
```

This would print the first word in the first line of your txt file. I used *space* as the separator but it actually depends on what separator you used in yout txt file when you were saving the info. For instance, you may want to use `"\t"` if `tab` was used as the separator.

Comment: i want to read the first word only, the words is the name of the accounts

Comment: `sc.nextLine()` gives you the first line. Reading a txt file in a line-by-line fashion is a very common practice. It is your job now to get whatever you want from the first line. See my update.

Comment: oh ok, but what if i want to display the first line based on the account, for example the account name is A and the username is B and the password is C, what should i do? what if the user log in using another account ?

Comment: (Just to build up on top of your model) you can check if the current line contains the keyword you want: `thisLine.contains(keyword);` If it does not have it, then you can move to the next line. If none of the lines contain such "username", then you can shoot an error: "Forgot your username?"

Comment: if you want to read the first word only, then instead of `line.split(" ")[1].toLowerCase()`, you have to try `line.split(" ")[0].toLowerCase()`, because index starts from `0`

Comment: For more questions, please take a look at the list of all methods you can use for Strings here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: but the username input is located on another form

Comment: Then go and get it. :)

Comment: For the record, I am only trying to help you in the way you are trying to design your project. In the real word, no one should be able to read people's username and password, not even the business owners, nor the developers.

Comment: String username = txtUser.getText; is it like this?, the txtUser is unknown because the text field is in another form

Comment: Yes, you get the username from what the user input to the textbox, and then find the line in the txt file which has that username as its second word, i.e., `words[1]`. When you found that line, you compare the password the user entered with the `words[2]` of that line. If they match, let them in. Otherwise, "Wrong password!".

Comment: omg thank you!. sorry i cant approve your question, my rep is still on 11